# syncdb ignores imported models

Tags: python, django-models, django-syncdb

I have a project, structured like this:

```
project/
   __init__.py
   db/
      models/
         __init__.py
         article.py
         project.py
         ontology/
            __init__.py
            coded.py
```

It's a little bit bigger, but that's the idea. `models.__init__.py` contains:

```
from db.models.article import *
from db.models.project import *
from db.models.ontology.coded import *
```

When running syncdb, it ignores all models imported in `models.__init__.py`. There are no `ImportError`'s, and when adding a print statement to the `__init__.py`, it happily prints the import models (while running syncdb).

Models *defined* in `__init__.py` work though.

Why is that? Can I force syncdb to account for my imported models?

Edit: The application *is* in INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'amcatnavigator.navigator',
'amcatnavigator.db',
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to South (syncdb) docs: http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part1.html It will create tables only for those models that are in INSTALLED_APPS section in settings.py file. If model is being used, but its changed and you don't want to lose any data - use migrations: http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part1.html#the-first-migration

UPDATE: As far as i looked Django by design wont find the models within different directories: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14007 you might want to use app_label

UPDATE: app_label docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `app_label = 'db'` to your models' Meta inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `db` module is not included in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your settings. It is not enough information for other variants.

Comment: I should have mentioned it's in INSTALLED_APPS. Added to original post in 3.. 2..