# How Django skipping an app when using syncdb command

Tags: django, syncdb

I have a Django project which has two apps (one created as debug test). For the debug test, syncdb does put the model in the database but for the other it does not.

- Both are in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.
- There are around seven models, none of them being recognized.
- Neither the server, any page or the syncdb-console give any errors.
- Models are in a [models directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111244/get-a-list-of-all-installed-applications-in-django-and-their-attributes). As a test, there is also one in app/models.py (doesn't work either).
- Most strikingly to me is that the below [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111244/get-a-list-of-all-installed-applications-in-django-and-their-attributes) does display the models which aren't synced (executed from the app that is skipped):

```py
for model in get_models():  
    models.append(model)  
pass models to a template
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I think it is something trivial but I'm out of ideas for things to try.

Thanks,

UPDATE:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (  
    'django.contrib.auth',  
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',  
    'django.contrib.sessions',  
    'django.contrib.messages',  
    'django.contrib.admin',  
    'techtree',  
    'froink',  
)
```

Structure:

- `project/techtree/models.py` (contains a test model)
- `project/techtree/models/__init__.py` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676441/django-models-arent-being-recognized-by-syncdb-or-south-after-they-have-been-re))
- `project/techtree/models/typ.py` (contains model Type)

There are more files of the same type as the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you missing the `__init__.py` file in the second app's models directory? That would mean it can't be found on the path.

Can you show us your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, and your directory structure please?

Looking at your directory structure, I think I can guess what's wrong.

```
my_app/
    __init__.py
    my_module.py
    my_module/
        __init__.py
        my_python_file.py
```

With the above fictional directory structure, what gets imported when I do the following?

```
from my_module import *
```

Does that import everything from within `my_module.py` or everything within the `my_module` directory?

Use one, or the other. Not both. Put everything inside your `models.py` file, and get rid of the directory unless you have a good reason for having a `models` directory. You probably don't.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added the requested info

Comment: Fck I'm stupid, should have thought of that... Thanks for the answer the test model in models.py is being recognized now! I'll see if I can get the directory to work (with models.py removed) and otherwise stick with this.

Comment: @Mark, putting all your models in one file in python is fairly natural. If you must separate them out into separate files, be sure to import all the externally accessible models in the `models/__init__.py` file. GL

Answer (score 2):

I faced this same problem, It took hours for me to figure out how to group models in to a separate directory. Heres how to do it,

Add a meta class to each of your models with an app_label parameter.

```
from django.db import models

class Test(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'myapp'
```

Here's where I found out about this,
[Placing Django Models In Separate Files](http://andrewwilkinson.wordpress.com/2009/01/20/placing-django-models-in-separate-files/)

But doing this wasn't enough you have to import the models in an `__init__.py` file in the models directory like this,

```
from YourModelFile import *
```

Answer (score 0):

Django is usually searching for a `models.py` file only. If you have `models.py` and a module sub directory called `models` with an `__init__.py` file it is not recognizing the models correctly (my guess). You can do one of these two:

- Remove your sub-module completely and keep all your model definitions in `models.py`

OR

- Remove `models.py` in `techtree`. Add a `models.py` file to your `techtree.models` app where you keep the model definitions. Add `'techtree.models'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` (just `'techtree'` is no enough).

Hope one of these answers helps.

Comment: Adding the the models directory to the installed apps will not work. INSTALLED_APPS is used for things like finding templates and static content as well - not just model definitions.

Comment: Adding means adding. Not removing the ``'techtree'`` and add ``'techtree.models'`` instead. Add both and templatetags and static files are available.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file name is

`__init__.py`

and not

init.py

Comment: Yeah that is a bit confusing, I typed __ init__ but I'm not very familiar with the language here so it made it bold instead of just displaying what I typed; sorry about that.